# responsive background image issue in HTML list

Tags: css, responsive-design, background, html-lists, responsive-images

Each of my `li` elements has a background image which I wanted to make responsive by using `background-size:contain;` But it does not work as expected which you can see live [here](http://demo.lumierebd.com/test/) ( you can get the responsive view tester by pressing Ctrl+Shift+m in Firefox while you are on that page ).

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">

    <ul class="menu_ul">
        <li>One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
        <li>Four</li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>

    body{

        width:50%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border:1px solid red;
    }
    .menu{

        width:36%;
    }
    .menu ul{
        border:1px solid red;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .menu li{

        list-style: none;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
        color:#ffffff;
        background-image: url("img/bg1.png");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:contain;
        background-position:center;
        text-align: center;
    } 
    .menu li:hover{

        background-image: url("img/bg2.png");
    }

</style>
```

How to make it responsive anyway ?

Comment: well, what did you expect exactly? the image gets resized to be contained, so its height varies proportionally to disminished width. At least it stays vertical aligned to center which is already an achievement (sorry for that last one)

Comment: @Kaddath,  when you shrink the window the image does not cover the full background.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve similar effect without background-image and it will be responsive. Here is an example with pseudo element and skew transformation:

```css
body {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.menu {
  width: 36%;
}

.menu ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000;
  transform: skew(-40deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.menu li:hover::before {
  opacity:0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="menu_ul">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You did not use the image as background

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed yes :) as i stated in the answer : **without background-image** .. as there is no need to have image since you can achieve the effect with pur CSS3 ;) and it will be responsive

Comment: but the background could be a picture without being merely black

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed in this case it's will be different .. i consider the image you are using and transform it to CSS ;) ... if it will be a generic image then we can consider another trick

Comment: The another trick is what we need. At the same time  the solution you gave can also be a part of the answer.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed by the way i guess it better to create effect using CSS than image especially for links as image can be difficult to handle in general ... each image will create an issue and you won't be able to have a generic solution

Answer (score 1):

With `contain` the background-image will always be fit into its container in a way that the whole image remains visible (as opposed to `cover`). In this case the height will be 100% of the container, the width will be in correct/original proportion to the height according to the original image proportions.

Since the `li` elements don't have a different height, the background image size won't change on smaller screens, which is the expected behaviour when using `contain`

If you want to change that, you can use `background-size: 100% 100%` to stretch that image across the whole width of the `li`elements. Since your background-image is not a photo, but a rather simple graphic image, this wil work nicely.

Comment: 'Since the li elements don't have a different height, the background image size won't change on smaller screens' - why is 'different height' necessary ?

Comment: It isn't "necessary", it's only the reason for the behaviour you see, as I explained in my answer. Did you try `background-size: 100% 100%`? I suppose that's what you are after...

Comment: your solution worked. I just don't  understand why different heights of the `li` elements would change the background size ?

Comment: because with `background-size: contain` the original image proportions (i.e. the width/height ratio) are kept. If the height of the container changes, the height of the image will be adapted to it, and as a consequence the width of the image will change too, in order to keept the original image proportions.